# Orbit camera around player while facing player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I ACCIDENTALLY programmed this function (it was just 2 lines or so) a few days ago to orbit the camera around the player with the mouse x input value, but now I just can't get it to work again. I saw many solutions, some even used LookAt, but my own function was really very simply.

My player is constructed like this:

```
 PlayerObject
        CharacterWithBones (child of PlayerObject)
        OverShoulderCamera (child of PlayerObject)
```

Could somebody tell me again how to orbit the mouse around the player so that the camera always faces the player?

I do swear that it was without LookAt, and it was really simple. But now all solutions that I can think of would be overkills.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# with Unity 3D: How do I make a camera move around an object when user moves mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117591/c-sharp-with-unity-3d-how-do-i-make-a-camera-move-around-an-object-when-user-mo)

Comment: @Eliasar Unfortunately not. I have already tried that. The function in that function rotates the camera away from the player. My camera always faced the player.

Comment: Then you should combine that with the [`LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) function to face your target

Comment: Ah, you are right. I looked at the wrong answer in the post that you mentioned. Yes, the given solution is indeed what I needed. My own solution was much stripped down (as I said, 1 or 2 lines), but that will help me. Thank you very much!